# How to add sub item in drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I using drop down list to show menus.however there are some menus having submenus like

```
-Movies 
       -In Cinemas now
       -Coming Soon
```

I succeed to write code for simple menus Where i have taken one drop down list and 
added some items as shown in code.Some items contains sub-item now question is how to add these sub-items in drop down list.

```
     <select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
                                <option value="1" >Home</option>
                                <option value="2" >Movies</option>
                                <option value="3" >T.V. Shows</option>
                                <option value="4" >Photos</option>
                                <option value="4" >Site Help</option>

                            </select>
```

but i am unable to add sub-items to the main items.please give any solution

Comment: Take a look at JQuery-UI.  There's a dropdown box that allows sub-items in it.

Comment: Why not use the jQuery-UI menu widget?

Comment: Or this: http://callmenick.com/post/slide-down-menu-with-jquery-and-css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If its in a form you should use optgroup.

```html
 <select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

From: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp

Comment: exactly what i wanted tnx

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap , for more details you can see the documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html) below  the topic
**Sub menus on dropdowns**:

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html

its just do that

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
  ...
  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">More options</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      ...
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```